# Curl error 6: Curl Can't resolve host name for verificatiion licence

Tags: laravel

i have buy a script , and for installation i have a step to verify and validate the licence
i install this on my vps with domain (ssl ok )

```
--
Illuminate \ Http \ Client \ ConnectionException
cURL error 6: Could not resolve host: https; Unknown error (see https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/libcurl-errors.html)
Previous exceptions
cURL error 6: Could not resolve host: https; Unknown error (see https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/libcurl-
errors.html) (0)



], $options))), function ($response) {
                    $response->cookies = $this->cookies;
                    $response->transferStats = $this->transferStats;
 
                    if ($this->tries > 1 && ! $response->successful()) {
                        $response->throw();
                    }
                });
            } catch (ConnectException $e) {
                throw new ConnectionException($e->getMessage(), 0, $e);
            }
        }, $this->retryDelay ?? 100);
    }
 
    /**
     * Parse multi-part form data.
     *
     * @param  array  $data
     * @return array|array[]
     */
    protected function parseMultipartBodyFormat(array $data)
    {
        return collect($data)->map(function ($value, $key) {
            return is_array($value) ? $value : ['name' => $key, 'contents' => $value];
```

before starting, I checked my firewall (no blocking, no refusal) I checked the SSL, I checked Curl SSL (ok)
I don't know what to watch at all.

Comment: `Could not resolve host: https;` this is telling me that cURL seems to think you're accessing a URL that's just `https;`.

Comment: its strange , because , i have install curl ssl and try and its ok *   maybe i need to remove curl full and reinstall only ssl?

Comment: I think you misunderstood my comment. I'm saying the error says the url is literally just the string `https;` . Usually you'd have a fuller URL of the form `https://example.com`

Comment: ok i see, but i dont know where i must enter full URL https , maybe in .env  . thank you  Apokryfos.

Answer (score 0):

finally the problem was rather simple:
the redirection http to https was not clearly defined, so the url could change when the request for https for a specific service was made, this caused an error. To correct this I passed a 301 redirect from http to https, this solved my problem